# Only overwrite the base class members of a derived object with values from a base object

Tags: c#, .net, polymorphism, clone, variable-assignment

I'm working with an API, and I created my own wrappers with interfaces derived from some of the classes defined in the API.

I'm trying to copy the values from a base object into a derived object without overwriting the derived object's derived members.

This is what I'd like to attempt:

```
        List<DerivedClass> derivedObjects = new List<DerivedClass>
        {
            new DerivedClass(randomVar),
        }

        // baseObject.Foo() returns a base class object, I want it to populate all the 
        // base class members of my derived object without modifying the derived members
        derivedObjects[0] = baseObject.Foo(derivedObjects[0]);
```

Unfortunately, this is the way the API works, I have to pass in an instantiated derived or base object, in order to get back the "same" base object but further populated with certain things I need.

Any idea how one could go about this?

Comment: Using reflection, you need to parse members and filter to clone the required ones.

Comment: [mcve] please - with real meaningful property names etc.

Comment: What about redesigning `DerivedClass` to no longer directly inherit `baseObject`, but instead _contain an instance of `baseObject`_?  Then it's as simple as swapping out the instance of `baseObject` inside your `DerivedClass`. (e.g. `derivedObjects[0].BaseObject = baseObject.Foo(derivedObjects[0].BaseObject);`)  If you want it to conform to some interface, where the properties live inside `baseObject`, you can always create wrappers that pass through those properties.